# Webpack file watcher on Gallium OS

Tags: webpack-dev-server

While this is technically an OS issue, it is effecting my deving so hoping that perhaps someone has run into something similar and has an idea as google and reddit have failed so far.

I have a chrombook running gallium which is simply a light *buntu flavour, and while it works near perfectly for dev, webpack-dev-server does not detect general files changes, only more drastic ones like merging in master.

As I do not have the same issue on my other 2 Ubuntu setups I can only image it is some small lib or something that Gallium simply did not include for whatever reason that is preventing file change emissions going up for webpack to pick up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> echo 100000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches